# Conditional expectation of $X$ given $\sin(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

What is the conditional expectation of $\mathbb{E}(X\mid\sin(X))$ if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,\pi]$?

Intuitively I expect that it is constant and equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, since the Borel set generated by $\sin(X)$ is symmetric around $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Is that true? What would be the formal proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that true?

Yes it is.

> What would be the formal proof?

A formal proof would be to show that $\mathbb E(Xu(\sin X))=\frac\pi2\mathbb E(u(\sin X))$ for every bounded measurable function $u$.

*Recall that in full generality, $\mathbb E(Y\mid Z)$ may be defined as the only $Z$-measurable random variable $T$ such that $\mathbb E(Yu(Z))=\mathbb E(Tu(Z))$ for every bounded measurable function $u$.* Use this for $Y=X$, $Z=\sin X$ and $T=\frac\pi2$.

A painless way to show that $\mathbb E(Xu(\sin X))=\frac\pi2\mathbb E(u(\sin X))$ is to start with the fact that $\pi-X$ and $X$ are identically distributed hence $(\pi-X,\sin(\pi-X))=(\pi-X,\sin X)$ and $(X,\sin X)$ are identically distributed. Thus, $(*)=\mathbb E(Xu(\sin X))$ solves the identity
$$
(*)=\mathbb E((\pi-X)u(\sin(X)))=\pi\mathbb E(u(\sin X))-(*),
$$
and the proof is complete.

Comment: I dont understand your first equation: $\mathbb{E}(Xu(\sin(x)))=\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbb{E}(u(sin(X)))$.

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: I have never seen that definition before. Do you have a reference, where the equivalence of the definitions is explained?

Comment: That this version implies the one with events (the only fact you need in the present case) is obvious: take only functions $u$ which are indicator functions. // Reference: a perky answer would be *any reference which does a good job at introducing conditional expectations*... :-) Anyway you could try David Williams, *Probability with martingales* (small book, extremely pleasant to read, simple to follow).

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{\pi}{2}$ is correct, yes.

Proof: We want to use the following theorem: $$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}) = Y \Leftrightarrow \forall G \in \mathcal{G}: \int_G Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_G X \, d\mathbb{P} \qquad (\ast)$$

where $G$ is a generator of the $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{F}$. In this case we can choose $\mathcal{G} = \{\{\sin X \leq y\}; y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Let $G = \{\sin X \leq y\} \in \mathcal{G}$, $y \in [0,1]$, then

$$\int_G X \, d\mathbb{P} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi x \cdot 1_{(-\infty,y]}(\sin x) \, dx  = \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \left( \int_0^{\arcsin y} x \,dx + \int_{\pi-\arcsin y}^{\pi} x \, dx \right) \\ = \ldots = \arcsin y = \ldots = \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \int_0^\pi \underbrace{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{=:Y} 1_{(-\infty,y]}(x) \, dx = \int_G \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Clearly the equality holds also for $y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash [0,1]$. From $(\ast)$ follows $\mathbb{E}(X|\sin X)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I am aware of the property for the conditional expectation that has been used but didn't get the following part in your answer. Would appreciate it if you can explain the step, $\arcsin y = \frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\pi}{2} 1_{(- \infty, y]} (x) \ dx$. I am an amateur in the field of probability distributions, so would appreciate it if you can explain the meaning of the term $1_{(- \infty, y]}$. What kind of distribution function is this?